# How do I allow specific attributes on tags with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, attributes

I have a string, for example: `<div style='text-align:center;' otherattr="script">`

I want to allow specific attributes, for example allowing only the style attribute.

It should return: `<div style='text-align:center;'>`

I want to allow the attributes style, href, src, and align.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is the question exactly ?

Comment: Is the JavaScript client side? Then I suggest to parse the string into a DOM element and get a list of its attributes (actually, you should do the same on the server side).

Comment: What you meen "what is the question"?

and i cant insert this to the DOM because there can be more than 50 attrs, i'm looking for regex expression to do that, i couldn't write it by my self =\

Comment: @user1317562: Obligatory comment for these kind of questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone said in the comments, the best way to do this is to parse the string as an element and use DOM methods on it. REGEX is generally a bad idea for DOM handling.

This will allow `id` attributes but remove any others.

```
    //prep
    var str = "<div id='something' class='something_else'></div>",
    allowed_attrs = ['id'],
    tmp_container = document.createElement('div'),;

    //parse string as element and retrieve it as one
    tmp_container.innerHTML = str;
    var div = tmp_container.querySelector('div');

    //remove any non-allowed attributes
    for (var i=0; i<div.attributes.length; i++)
        if (allowed_attrs.indexOf(div.attributes[i].name) == -1)
            div.removeAttribute(div.attributes[i].name);

    //check
    alert(tmp_container.innerHTML); //<div id='something'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks man, but may be there is another option expect creating new element? because theres an option for more than 50 elements, so i think it will realy slow..

i meen for some regex..

Comment: DOM scripting is fine for 50 elements - it's only when you get to the late hundreds or thousands that it can cause slow-down. And we're not appending them to the DOM (i.e. causing browser repaints) so that is another big saving. I'd go with it.

Comment: Ok if you say so, thanks man, if someone can giv aregex, it will be great.

Comment: The problem with REGEX for this sort of thing is REGEX wasn't built for parsing. So if your HTML is even slightly malformed or - more likely - unpredictable - the pattern will break. Honestly, it's not a wise path to go down. You can do the DOM stuff but in a loop. If you insist on REGEX please at least consider a vote-up for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery

```
var tmp = $('<div style="text-align:center;" otherattr="script">');
var elem = $('<div>');
elem.attr('style', tmp.attr('style'))
elem.attr('href', tmp.attr('href'))
elem.attr('src', tmp.attr('src'))
elem.attr('align', tmp.attr('align'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match only the attributes you specified, you can then copy and paste the matches in a new tag to substitute the one you started from

```
(style|href|src|align)=((".+?[^\\]")|('.+?[^\\]'))
```

Comment: What is this? Doen't look like JavaScript.

Comment: This is a regex, according to the request made in a comment by the asker.